# Create donut chart vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a donut chart from a value that I have defined and 1 - the value I have defined. This value is not stored in any cells but is just store in a long variable. How do I source the data to these two values? I want the chart to be saved in a variable as I need to paste it into a PowerPoint presentation.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function creates a chart in Excel in its own sheet and returns a reference to it. You can copy/paste it into powerpoint then you can eventually get rid of it by using delete.

```
Function CreateTwoValuesPie(ByVal x As Double) As Chart
  Set CreateTwoValuesPie = Charts.Add
  CreateTwoValuesPie.ChartType = XlChartType.xlPie ' or .xlDoughnut
  With CreateTwoValuesPie.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "This is a two-value Pie"
    .Values = Array(x, 1 - x)
  End With
End Function

Sub Testing()
  Dim ch As Chart
  Set ch = CreateTwoValuesPie(0.6)

  ' Now copy/paste ch to PowerPoint or do whatever with it
  ' Then if you want to get rid of it in Excel:
  ch.Delete
End Sub
```